# Devise Resetting Password. Don't redirect, send back Ajax success?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

New to rails.  Got a question.

After requesting to change your password using Devise, it wants to redirect to some path.  I have overridden this path using:

```
protected def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  root_path
end
```

However, this is really a stop-gap until I figure out how to get a JSON object to pass back to my Forgot Password page that now uses AJAX.  Is there a way to pass back a JSON object to the calling Forgot page after the resetting password instructions are sent instead of redirecting?

EDITED:

Added PasswordsController and what it looks like:

```
class Portal::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def create
    super
  end
end
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I ended up doing.

First, I looked at the devise source code and it seems it's hard coded to redirect (3.5.1) or return to the Forgot Password if the email fails to send.

So, I think I'm barking up the wrong tree as far as getting JSON out of Devise naturally.

So my solution was to mimic what Devise does, in this way:

```
class Portal::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  respond_to :json, only: [:create]

  def create
    user = User.send_reset_password_instructions(params.fetch(:user))

    if successfully_sent?(user)
      render json: { data: "something" }, status: 200
    else
      render json: { data: "something bad" }, status: 400
    end
  end
end
```

This still seems to update the database and user record with the token and date information if it's successful.

Granted, I don't like doing this; I would rather AJAX be available right out of the box, but it is what it is.

Hope that helps.